# How to check for empty drop zone in drag and drop jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, submit, dropzone.js, is-empty

My website has a form and a button that shouldn't be activated until the form is completed. This is true for all the boxes except for the image dropzone.

How can I verify that the button is inactive unless the dropzone is filled? The 'add' button should only be active when the boxes and image is uploaded.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='content'>
    <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone"></form>  
  </div> 
</div>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $(".dropzone").dropzone({
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            removedfile: function(file) {
                var name = file.name;    

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'upload.php',
                    data: {name: name,request: 2},
                    sucess: function(data){
                        console.log('success: ' + data);
                    }
                });
                var _ref;
                return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
            }
        });
        </script>


<form  action="upload.php"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 

     <textarea  name="description" id="description" required></textarea>
     <input type="text" name="phone" >
      <div class='actions'>
        <input name="save"type="submit" value="Add" disabled="disabled">
         </div> 
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="text"], textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    var textarea_value = $("#description").val();
    var phone_value = $('input[name="phone"]').val();

    if (textarea_value == '' || phone_value == ''  )
      $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else 
      $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);          
  });
});
```

Comment: Based on what you posted, this seems correct. What is not working? If you need more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: but once i fill the form the button is active even if i don"t upload a photo. i want the button th stay unclickable until a photo is uploaded alongside the filled boxes

Comment: I do not know what you mean by '*the button*', I do not see a button in your example. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: <form  action="upload.php"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
   
     <textarea  name="description" id="description" required></textarea>
  <input type="text" name="phone" >
   <div class='actions'>
  <input name="save"type="submit" value="Add" disabled="disabled">
   </div> 
</form>